# How To Get Actual Stock Prediction Out of xgboost, caret and Quantmod (R)

Tags: r, r-caret, quantmod, xgboost

I'm learning R and Quantmod and built a really simple stock model prediction. I have both a xgboost and caret model, here's the whole example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
# get market data
Nasdaq100_Symbols <- c("AAPL", "ADBE", "ADI", "ADP", "ADSK", "AKAM")
getSymbols(Nasdaq100_Symbols)

# merge them all together
nasdaq100 <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, ADBE, ADI, ADP, ADSK, AKAM)))
# set outcome variable
outcomeSymbol <- 'ADP.Volume'

# shift outcome value to be on same line as predictors
nasdaq100 <- xts(nasdaq100,order.by=as.Date(rownames(nasdaq100)))
nasdaq100 <- as.data.frame(merge(nasdaq100, lm1=lag(nasdaq100[,outcomeSymbol],-1)))
nasdaq100$outcome <- ifelse(nasdaq100[,paste0(outcomeSymbol,'.1')] > nasdaq100[,outcomeSymbol], 1, 0)

# remove shifted down volume field
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[,!names(nasdaq100) %in% c(paste0(outcomeSymbol,'.1'))]

# cast date to true date and order in decreasing order
nasdaq100$date <- as.Date(row.names(nasdaq100))
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[order(as.Date(nasdaq100$date, "%m/%d/%Y"), decreasing = TRUE),]

# calculate all day differences and populate them on same row
GetDiffDays <- function(objDF,days=c(10), offLimitsSymbols=c('outcome'), roundByScaler=3) {
  # needs to be sorted by date in decreasing order
  ind <- sapply(objDF, is.numeric)
  for (sym in names(objDF)[ind]) {
    if (!sym %in% offLimitsSymbols) {
      print(paste('*********', sym))
      objDF[,sym] <- round(scale(objDF[,sym]),roundByScaler)

      print(paste('theColName', sym))
      for (day in days) {
        objDF[paste0(sym,'_',day)] <- c(diff(objDF[,sym],lag = day),rep(x=0,day)) * -1
      }
    }
  }
  return (objDF)
}

# call the function with the following differences
nasdaq100 <- GetDiffDays(nasdaq100, days=c(1,2,3,4,5,10,20), offLimitsSymbols=c('outcome'), roundByScaler=2)

# drop most recent entry as we don't have an outcome
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[2:nrow(nasdaq100),]

# use POSIXlt to add day of the week, day of the month, day of the year
nasdaq100$wday <- as.POSIXlt(nasdaq100$date)$wday
nasdaq100$yday <- as.POSIXlt(nasdaq100$date)$mday
nasdaq100$mon<- as.POSIXlt(nasdaq100$date)$mon

# remove date field and shuffle data frame
nasdaq100 <- subset(nasdaq100, select=-c(date))
nasdaq100 <- nasdaq100[sample(nrow(nasdaq100)),]

# xgboost Modeling
library(xgboost)
predictorNames <- names(nasdaq100)[names(nasdaq100) != 'outcome']

set.seed(1234)
split <- sample(nrow(nasdaq100), floor(0.7*nrow(nasdaq100)))
train <-nasdaq100[split,]
test <- nasdaq100[-split,]

bst <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(train[,predictorNames]),
               label = train$outcome,
               verbose=0,
               eta = 0.1,
               gamma = 50,
               missing = NaN,
               nround = 150,
               colsample_bytree = 0.1,
               subsample = 1,
               nthread = 4,
               objective="binary:logistic")

predictions <- predict(bst, as.matrix(test[,predictorNames]), missing = NaN, outputmargin=TRUE)

library(pROC)
auc <- roc(test$outcome, predictions)
print(paste('AUC score:', auc$auc))
```

Question 1:
Right now it trains on 70%, predicts on 30%, and I can print out an AUC score at the end. Say I train on 100% and want to predict what will happen tomorrow? I.e. get the symbols whose volume the model will think goes up tomorrow.

Question 2:
Ideally I want to keep adding today's end of day data into the model, and then have it predict tomorrow's symbols. Right now it seems I'd have to use `getSymbols()` to pull the entire history again. Any way to just pull today's data and append it to that symbol's xts object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single answer to Question 1, and it's not entirely clear what you mean when you say "pick tomorrow's stock symbols" (for what purpose?).   I'm speculating that your aim is probably to try and predict which stocks will outperform/underperform over some future horizon (e.g. tomorrow's trading session) and act on those predictions.

The answer to your question really depends on how you define your model and how you will pick your stocks based on the predictions you obtain.  Maybe choosing a model that has optimised AUC is a good choice for classifying stock return signs ... or maybe other metrics could work better (there is no single right answer).

The model you use involves making many decisions.  You could use classification for return signs as you've suggested, or you can estimate the returns using are regression approach instead of using a classification model.  You may want to filter your predictions you obtain from your model somehow before you decide to "pick tomorrow's stock symbols".  The options are endless ...  the hard part is finding what actually works.  And I doubt anyone here is going to tell you what does work well for obvious reasons ;)

Question 2,

Use the `from` and `to` arguments for `getSymbols` if you want to collect data via Yahoo using `quantmod`.  Specifically look at `?getSymbols.yahoo`, and/or print the source code (i.e. `print(getSymbols.yahoo)`).  Also, you might find `end` as in `end(xts_object)` useful to give the latest timestamp in your xts object, before making the getSymbols request to update the data you have stored already.

`getSymbols(Symbols = "AAPL", from = "2014-01-01", to = "2014-12-31")`

*Update:*

```
# Get data for 2014
sym <- "AAPL"
md <- new.env()
getSymbols(Symbols = sym, from = "2014-01-01", to = "2014-12-31", env = md)
last_date <- end(get(sym, md))
new <- getSymbols(Symbols = sym, from = last_date + 1, to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign=  FALSE)
assign(x = sym, value = rbind(get(sym, md), new), envir = md)
head(md$AAPL, 3)
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2014-01-02    555.68    557.03   552.02     553.13    58671200      74.11592
# 2014-01-03    552.86    553.70   540.43     540.98    98116900      72.48790
# 2014-01-06    537.45    546.80   533.60     543.93   103152700      72.88317
tail(md$AAPL, 3)
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2017-02-22    136.43    137.12   136.11     137.11    20745300        137.11
# 2017-02-23    137.38    137.48   136.30     136.53    20704100        136.53
# 2017-02-24    135.91    136.66   135.28     136.66    21690900        136.66
```

Comment: For question one, say the scenario is whether or not the volume will go up tomorrow.  So the training model is by day, and each symbol that has it's volume go up the next day gets a 1, else it gets 0. Just edited question to include equation. So now instead of training, I want to know, based on all the data, which symbols will get a 1 tomorrow (i.e. the model thinks their volume will go up.

Comment: For question 2, I knew I could specify a date for getSymbols, but it just wrote over the previous xts.  I'll have to look into combining it with `end` so it just adds it.

Comment: @Alteredorange What your asking for question 1 is either trivial or I don't understand what you mean.  Your predictions indicate to you which stocks may have higher volume tomorrow.

For question 2, of course you need to append your new data to your old data, where the old data you store in a variable with a different name and/or ideally in a different environment.  You haven't really made that clear in your question.  How you do that should be straight forward.  Just `rbind(old_OHLC_xts_data, new_data)`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this, and I can't find any solid tutorials online :( As far as predictions, does that always just predict the next day? My `predictions` is just rows of `nope
yes
1
0.9962924
0.003707607
2
0.9962670
0.003733027`  I also haven't used environments yet, so I'll look into that too.  Thanks for all the help and clarification, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Added more details for one way you could store data for Q2.  How you respond to your prediction values in Q1 is up to you.  If you're returning estimated probs from your classifier, a basic approach would be choose a probability cutoff beyond which you estimate the stock volume tomorrow will be higher than normal (outcome 1).  You should understand how to do this if you're using AUC correctly in the first place.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the additional details. Edited question with entire code, so you can run the whole thing if you want to. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problems but I am trying to find the Confidence of a Trading Strategy using the caret package (through the "gafs" functions it has).

To answer the first part of your question, training your data on the 100% of the Historical Data, you will be executing "*Overfitting*" which cause your future predictions to be highly unreliable. Check this [link](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/overfitting.asp) out for a detailed understanding about Overfitting. I recommend you explore [Investopedia.com](http://www.Investopedia.com) further to understand this concept.

To my amazement, the caret package not only offers you methods to divide your dataset i.e. the Historical Data into a one-time chunks of say 70% and 30% but offers multiple chunks for cross-validations in a single go of say, Genetic Algorithm's function.

Comment: Thanks Abdul! I'm looking into gafs, do you have any favorite tutorials? I've also learned a little bit more about r and understand cross validation. But it also looks like gafs only looks for one outcome, where in this scenario I would have multiple outcomes (i.e. however many symbols I put into the model).  Can gafs handle that?

Comment: nothing much brother. apart from some videos at youtube, i took this Datacamp's tutorial on Machine Learning:-
https://www.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-toolbox